# Duda sobre lenguaje Kotlin

Tags: array, string, funciones, kotlin

Por qué y para qué se escribe la función `main` de la siguiente forma:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println("Hello, World!")
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué es exactamente lo que no entiendes?

Comment: Ya me lo aclaró Angel Oropeza, gracias. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ¿Por qué?

Por convención el punto de inicio de un programa en *Kotlin* es una función con una firma como `main(args: Array<String>)`, donde `args` representa los argumentos de línea de comandos pasados ​​al programa.

> ¿Para qué?

Para permitir pasar argumentos desde la línea de comandos. Esto se logra utilizando los tipos de datos básicos como son [Strings](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#strings) y [Arrays](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#arrays)

Si deseas probar la función `main` enviando parámetro puedes ingresar a este enlace:

- [Reading a name from the command line.kt](https://try.kotlinlang.org/#/Examples/Hello,%20world!/Reading%20a%20name%20from%20the%20command%20line/Reading%20a%20name%20from%20the%20command%20line.kt) (*Leyendo un nombre desde la linea de comandos.kt*)

También es importante hacer notar que a partir de **Kotlin 1.3** podrás definir la función `main` sin parámetros (*[Parameterless main](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew13.html#parameterless-main)*) en caso de no requerir este comportamiento de la siguiente forma:

```
fun main() {
    println("Hello, world!")
}
```

Por último, podrían interesar los siguientes enlaces:

- [How do I run my program?](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/native/faq.html#q-how-do-i-run-my-program) (*¿Cómo ejecuto mi programa?*)
- [Working with the Command Line Compiler](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/command-line.html#creating-and-running-a-first-application) (*Trabajar con el compilador de línea de comandos*)